# What type is 'pass' in Python?

Tags: python

The `pass`statement is usually a placeholder for future code and is used as a `null` operation.

But why it's not defined a `type` in Python. Should't it belong to `None` type?

Comment: `pass` is not an object. It is a statement. It's like asking what is the type of `continue` or `break`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects have types. Statements do not. `pass` is a statement, and does not have a type. (Also, `None` is not a type.)

Comment: `None` is a `NoneType` object.  `>>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: @cryptonome: Yes, None is an object, so it is an instance of some type, specifically NoneType. That doesn't mean it *is* a type, though; I've seen a bunch of questions where people get confused about that.

Comment: given that `NoneType` is a class object from `object`, which is a metaclass from `type`, then `NoneType`, like the name suggested, derived from `type` just like any other `object`. check `help(NoneType)`.

Comment: @cryptonome: I can't tell what you're trying to say, and it doesn't seem relevant. `object` is not a metaclass, and "derived from `type` just like any other `object`" doesn't make sense.

Comment: ps: you said it in your answer, object has types. that contradicts the last statement you made, `None` is not a type`, since `None` _is_ an object. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/10254804

Comment: @cryptonome: I know what a metaclass is and how metaclasses work. The things you said still don't make sense.

Comment: Having a type and being a type are different things.

Comment: hmm i see, alright. I was going to argue further since `None` is a singleton but i understand your point now